# Premiere Pro offline transcription engine via CLI?

Tags: premiere, audio, transcription

How can you access Premiere's local transcription engine outside of Premiere? Is there CLI access? I want the raw (hopefully JSON) data for analysis and additional per-word processing with time codes.

Comment: Not from Premiere, but I've had pretty amazing results using Whisper on an M1 mac. It doesn't do word by word, but generates line by line with timecode for subtitles.  The large model is remarkably accurate - I'd say almost comparable to a human. https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp